# Multiplying two columns in sql and obtain as a result in the column and it should be in descending order

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to add a result to the column by multiplying two columns and obtain the result in descending order.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT whid, max_pallets, cost_per_pallet, (max_pallets * cost_per_pallet) as maximum cost 
FROM WAREHOUSE 
ORDER BY maximum cost Desc;
```

whenever I execute this statement it's getting error like:

> Error at line 1: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 2):

You missed double quotes around `maximum cost`

```
SELECT whid, max_pallets, cost_per_pallet, (max_pallets * cost_per_pallet)
as "maximum cost" FROM WAREHOUSE ORDER BY "maximum cost" Desc
```

Comment: Based on the error it's Oracle (not MySQL), so you really need quotes.

Comment: I removed the confusing tag from the question.